# Web interface to manage users created with FOSUserBundle

Tags: user-management, symfony

Is there an existing web interface, which could ease the management of users created with [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) in a Symfony (2 or 3) project? Typically it would be presented as a bundle extension of FOSUserBundle.

To justify my question, here is a dead simple problem I met: I didn't find any simple/direct way to list all the existing users; I have either to look directly into the database, or to write a dedicated PHP page (which can be considered equivalent to writing a tiny manager).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found exactly what I was looking for:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html